# The current path, signup, didn't match any of these in django project

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I am using Django for a project but getting following error.
[image]

It was running perfectly before.

I guess, path is not matching in my import.
Can I get some hint regarding the path?

My directory looks like this:
[image]

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('settings', views.settings, name='settings'),
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('follow', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    path('profile/<str:pk>', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('like-post', views.like_post, name='like-post'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signin', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
```

Can I get some hint to get rid of this error?
Thank you

Comment: Try adding "/" to your urls, according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/) it could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just add "/" after signup in urls like this

```
path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
```

Comment: Please declare my answer as right answer if it's working for you

Comment: Already solved the problem, This is what I did to solve problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should add slashes to the urls in urls.py because it is necessary according to the django official documentation.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('settings/', views.settings, name='settings'),
    path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('follow/', views.follow, name='follow'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('like-post/', views.like_post, name='like-post'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
```